# If xy determines z can x determine z and y determine z?

Tags: mysql, functional-dependencies

It is a functional dependency question.

I know that when x->yz then x->y and x->z.But is the above dependency possible?

Comment: You cannot remove arbitrarily attributes from the left hand side of a dependency, so the answer is no.

Comment: You are not clear. Please rephrase. You don't mean "the above dependency", because there is not single dependency you can be talking about. You mean, can the above consequece hold if its premise holds. Or just don't try to reference the title, put it into your question.

Comment: @Renzo I think they mean, can xy->z, x->y & y->z all at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If xy determines z can x determine z and y determine z?

Yes, if xy -> z then it's possible that also x -> z and y -> z.

Suppose z can only have one value; then a given x, y or xy only ever appears with that one value. Or suppose x -> z and y -> z and x must equal y. Or suppose both x and y are unique; then xy is unique. (A case of that is when both x & y are candidate keys.) In fact *any time* that x -> z and y -> z, xy -> z.

(To show something is possible it's always worth trying some cases, especially very simple ones, in case they are examples, so you don't have to prove the general case.)